# Gnuplot y-axis value from x(dates)

Tags: date, gnuplot

I would like to know how the y can take value from the x (the x store the dates)
i have the following dates

```
13/3/2014   218.11.11
12/4/2014   218.37.12
5/5/2014    218.31.34
7/5/2015    218.31.10
23/5/2014   218.32.21
4/6/2014    218.41.14
```

we have these dates and these ips i want store the ips in months 
example:
5/2014 - 3 IPS

in gnuplot the graph i want to print every how much ips has every month 
here is what i have until now

```
set xlabel 'Date'
set title 'Gnuplot test graph'
set ylabel 'IPS'
set terminal png size 1400,500
set datafile sep ','

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set xrange ["2009/3/27 00:00":"2014/4/11 22:28"]

set xtics nomirror rotate by -45
set grid
set term png
set output 'file.png'

plot 'data.dat'using 1:2 with points
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to count the number of equal x-values, you can use `plot ... smooth frequency` using a fixed number of `1` for the y-values:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%d/%m/%Y'
plot 'data.dat' using 1:(1) smooth frequency
```

This plots the number of entries for each day.

To group the values by month, you must normalize all values for a month to the first of this month. For this you can use the `tm_mday` function, which gets you the day of the current month, based on a timestamp:

```
set yrange [0:*]
set xdata time
set timefmt '%d/%m/%Y'
set xrange['01/03/2014':'01/06/2014']
set xtics 30*24*60*60
set format x '%b %Y'
plot 'data.dat' using (timecolumn(1) - (tm_mday(timecolumn(1))-1)*24*60*60):(1) smooth frequency w lp pt 7 ps 2 notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude but im getting this error: "test.conf", line 7: all points y value undefined!

Comment: Probably, for a first test, you must remove the `set xrange` and `set xtics` commands, which I used only to place the labels properly for the test data you provided.

Comment: i removed xrange and xtics and i get this: Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]

Comment: ok i just played with it a bit and i removed only set xrange the results are these: http://i.imgur.com/JkSAj7R.png

Comment: Thanks alot my friend! played with it a bit more and changed the data.dat file, now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/LqVHBgt.png  this is what i wanted im still trying to understand your code im new to gnuplot and seems a bit hard to me. 1 more think if you can how can i make yrange shows exacly the number? i mean it now starts from 0 and then goes to 50, also can i change the bullet to cross? (using points) thank you.