# Plot number of requests per minute from timestamp csv

Tags: gnuplot

I have a .csv file with unix-timestamps, each timestamp depicts one request on a server.

Now I would like to plot a diagram of the number of requests for each minute/hour in the diagram.
Like a load-diagram.

How can this be done using gnuplot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gnuplot can plot such diagrams. In your case I suggest to use the `boxes` plotting style which, in contrast to the `histogram` style, uses a conventional numerical axis.

To count the requests per minute or per hour you must bin the time values properly. To do that, use the `tm_*` functions which gnuplot provides, to cut off the seconds or minutes and bin the data properly to full minutes or full hours (see also [Gnuplot y-axis value from x(dates)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27259023/2604213)).

To bin to minutes, use

```
bin_minutes(t) = t - tm_sec(t)
```

This just subtracts the seconds from the original time stamp. This would map all values with seconds from 0 to 59 to the same minute. To have the boxes centered properly between 0 and 59 seconds, add 30 seconds.

```
bin_minutes(t) = t - tm_sec(t) + 30
```

To bin to hours, use

```
bin_hours(t) = t - tm_min(t)*60 + 30*60 - tm_sec(t)
```

Furthermore, you must know, that gnuplot 4.6. uses the 1. Jan 2000 as reference for all time functions, and gnuplot 5.0 uses the 1. Jan 1970, like a normal Unix timestamp. So, depending on your gnuplot version you must subtract an offset from your Unix time stamp in order to get the correct values (see also the discussion in my answer to [Can I plot times when they're given as UNIX timestamps with added milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923816/2604213)).

Putting all together should give a working script (cannot test it since you didn't post any data):

```
set yrange [0:*]
set xdata time
offset = (GPVAL_VERSION < 5.0 ? 946684800 : 0)
bin_minutes(t) = t - tm_sec(t) + 30
bin_hours(t) = t - tm_min(t)*60 + 30*60 - tm_sec(t)

plot 'file.dat' using (bin_minutes($1-offset)):(1) smooth frequency title 'requests per minute',\
     '' using (bin_hours($1-offset)):(1) smooth frequency title 'requests per hour'
```